# Check if value is in array in php

Tags: php

I have this `$list` array which is something like this:

```
array (size=4)
  0 => string '-1' (length=2)
  1 => string '1' (length=1)
  2 => string '2' (length=1)
  3 => string '3' (length=1)
```

The problem is, when I try the following code it doesn't go to the `//do something line`:

```
if ((in_array("-1", $list, true)) {
    do something;
}
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @pr1nc3 I have tried it and still nothing. Yes, the array is always single dimensional

Comment: What is that `do something`? is it an echo?

Comment: @pr1nc3, yes, simple echo

Comment: how don't you get a syntax error. remove the first parenthesis from if.

Comment: @pr1nc3 nope, no error yet, and I have tried to debug it, and it just skips this one

Comment: This should result in an parse error. You're opening 3 paranthesis, but closing only 2. Are you sure you've provided the correct code?

Answer (score 4):

You have too many brackets in your if statement, it should look like this

```
if (in_array("-1", $list, true)) {
    do something;
}
```

Comment: Solves it for me [example here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/53c482adc163ba5553dafa829dc98137d484dd77)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$list =array (
  0 =>  '-1',
  1 =>  '1',
  2 =>  '2',
  3 =>  '3',
    );

if (in_array("-1", $list , true)) {
    echo "Here";
}
```

tried this code and it works just fine. Echo's the result as it should. If it does not solve it for you then the error is somewhere else. Provide with full code.